# Single Click Join a SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-permissions

I've created a group on SharePoint that allows users to join or add themselves.

As it is, I have a link that says "click here to join" which takes them to the group page and they can click ***actions-> join group.***

Is there a way to make this a single click solution?
I would like them to be able to click and simply be added to the group.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a button or hyperlink with full function of Join Group (programmatically).

Here is a sample script you can use using Script Editor web part on a classic page. Remember to change the group `ID` accordingly:

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
var user;
var membersGroup;
function addUser2Members() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
     
    // Get the members group using ID.
    membersGroup = groupCollection.getById(<ID>);

    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var userCollection = membersGroup.get_users();
    userCollection.addUser(user);
    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.load(membersGroup);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert(' Congratulations!' + '\n \n ' + user.get_title() + ' \n \n' + ' Has successfully joined the SharePoint Group:' + '\n \n ' + membersGroup.get_title());
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function callAddUser() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addUser2Members, "sp.js");
}
</script>
<input onclick="javascript:callAddUser();" type="button" value="Join Now!"/>
```

It returns a prompt window that the user joins the group successfully after clicking.

Reference: [Creating a "Join Group" shortcut.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a536e8f-6a5f-4ad1-8ec2-90a4aca115e5/creating-a-join-group-shortcut?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

---

**UPDATE:**

You can style the button using **CSS** as following:

```
<style>
#JoinGroup{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0099CC;
    border-radius: 5px solid #0099CC;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Specify the custom button `Id` as:

```
<input onclick="javascript:callAddUser();" type="button" Id="JoinGroup" value="Join Now!"/>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! IS there any way to customize the button?
I found things like the below but can't seem to get it to apply.

color: #0099CC; /* Text color */
 
background-color: transparent; /* Remove background color */
 
border: 2px solid #0099CC; /* Border thickness, line style, and color */
 
border-radius: 5px; /* Adds curve to border corners */
 
text-transform: uppercase; /* Make letters uppercase */

Comment: @user94465 Please see the updated answer.